# International SEO Currency & Google Snippets

Tags: seo, ecommerce, rich-snippets, internationalization, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have an Australian Ecommerce site. I also sell to NZ and USA .  As part of the user experience it will detect where you are and change the currency accordingly. so when google crawls - the currency will always be USD I guess ( because it is a US IP address )

My question - how can I embed ecommerce microdata that will show the correct currency / price to the correct country in SERPS ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: You cannot. The SERPs are not conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on Moz Found the answer for me:

http://moz.com/community/q/international-seo-ecommerce-rich-snippets#reply_292857

Here is an example of a mark-up for multiple currencies:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Google Nexus 7">
  <meta itemprop="sku" content="abc123">
  <meta itemprop="gtin14" content="00886227537143" />
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="229.95" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="27800" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="JPY" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The example is coming from a reliable source: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6069143?hl=en

Comment: I would be interested more in seeing how this works. It may be that the ccTLD versions of Google is where the effect takes place and not necessarily in google.com. That suspicion is based on what I know about search. If it does work in google.com that would be new to me and I am all about learning!! Please- let me know what you find. Please update your answer with an details on where and how this has worked out for you. Valuable stuff.

Comment: I have implemented this setup on my site for the last 6 months, but search engines still don't seem to be able to distinguish between currencies. In fact the pricing snippets are now lost altogether.